# Line path becomes masked when UIImageView inserted

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

When inserting a UIImageView (which is masked by setting the `MaskView` property) the line that was drawn before also becomes masked.

[image]

The lines were first drawn animated using a `UIBezierPath` `CAShapeLayer` and `CABasicAnimation`

Is there a way to keep the lines drawn or do I have to draw them again?

Comment: So I realised after that I was drawing the lines on the first UIView in the hierarchy (below the inserted UIImageView) so that makes sense why the lines were being masked. Tried a few things before settling on drawing the lines again.